# vim - how to select multiple lines?

Tags: vim

Say I have this text:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get host
db_host=$(echo "dbhost") 
# Get DB name
db_name=$(echo "dbname")
# Get user
db_user=$(echo "dbuser")
# Get password
db_pass=$(echo "dbpass")
```

and I want to select every variable name and produce this output below the text:

```
echo "db_host: $db_host"
echo "db_name: $db_name"
echo "db_user: $db_user"
echo "db_pass: $db_pass"
```

On [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) for example I'd highlight `=$(` and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> multiple times, go back to the start of the line, copy with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, go to the last line and create a new one, paste, highlight all new lines, hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> and then add whatever I want.

I'm using `vim multiple cursors` but I'm not sure this is the way to go. Any directions?

Comment: Do you mean to transform that text into the new one, or to produce the new text in addition? Is that the entirety of text? Is the width of the variables always the same?... There's many directions you could take...

Comment: 1 thing I managed to do is record a macro.
qd0vwhyGoecho "<esc>pA: $<esc>pA"q

Comment: Add the text to the same file, 1 line below the last line. This is the entire text. the width should be the same (1 `w` motion to select the variable name).
I managed to do it with macro but it took more time than I'd like it to be.

Comment: Why are you using a subshell echo to assign these plain strings to variables?

Comment: @PaulHodges Excellent question, though unrelated to the present one :P

Comment: @PaulHodges I am actually not, this is not the real code :) This is just dummy code for the question.

Answer (score 4):

There's many ways you could do it. Here's one: Starting with cursor at start of first `db_host`:

```
yGGp              Yank everything, paste at the bottom
:.,$g/^#/d<CR>    In the pasted part, remove all comment lines
<C-O>             Back to start of the pasted part
<C-V>GI           Select the first column, prepend
echo "<Esc>
f=<C-V>           Then select the block from equals to quote, change
f"Gc
: $<Esc>
f)<C-V>           Then select the block at the closing brace, change
G$c
;<Esc>
```

Another approach, using macros and registers, starting at the same position:

```
qqq               Clear register q
qwq               Clear register w
qq                Start recording macro in q
yaw               yank a word (db_name) to default register
o                 open a new line below, and start insert
echo "
<C-R>"            insert the content of the default register (db_name)
: $
<C-R>"            insert the content of the default register (db_name) again
"<Esc>
"Wdd              the line is done; yank-append to register w
j0                skip the comment line, position at the start of the next variable
@q                execute the q macro (which is currently empty, but not for long)
q                 save the q macro
@q                execute the q macro (which will recurse, and slurp up all lines)
"wp               paste all the accumulated lines at the bottom
```

Third one, using regexp:

```
:.,$v/^#/t$<CR>   copy all non-comment lines to the end
:-3,.s/\(\w\+\).*/echo "\1: $\1"/<CR>
                  I didn't set a mark so manual range from 3 lines above:
                  capture the first word, discard everything else,
                  replace with what we want (obviously, could have done
                  visual selection instead of manually setting range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it:

First, create the echo lines with a substitution:

```
:%s/\(db_\w\+\)=\$(echo "\w\+")/&\recho "\1: $\1"
```

Note the `&` in the replace, which is the whole matched line. Followed by `\r` for a new line.

Then, empty a register you will use for it (`a` in my case):

```
qaq
```

Then cut all the echo lines in the said register:

```
:g/^echo /d A
```

Finally, go where you want them to be, and paste the content of the register:

```
"ap
```

Answer (score 0):

## A slightly different solution:

```
:g/echo/t$
:-3,.normal! ywccecho "<Ctrl-v><Ctrl-r>0: $<Ctrl-v><Ctrl-r0"
```

## Explanation

```
:g ................... global command
/echo/ ............... applied on each line that has "echo"
t$ ................... copy to the end
```

The cursor will move to the end, so we set the interval to the minus three lines until the current line `-3,.`

```
yw ................... copy the first word
cc ................... start chnanging the whole line
echo " ............... inserts a literal `echo "`
Ctrl-v Ctrl-r 0 ...... inserts the word we copied
```

Note: To insert the register zero `0` we must type <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

## Using a substitute command instead of a normal one

The second command could be a substitution

```
:-3,.s/\v(^\w+).*/echo "\1: $\1"
```

## How the vim solution could be a smarter solution?

If you have hundreds or thousands of lines to change, I think multiple cursors will not help that much, specially if the pattern interleaved over multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I missed what you are trying to do, but if I understood correctly, you just want to update the format of your output.

Try this:

```
:g/[(]echo "/s/echo "\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)$/echo "\1"\2^Mecho "\1: $\1"/
```

> NOTE: that ^M is a single control character, NOT a carat and then an M.
>   ***See below.***

Before -

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get host
db_host=$(echo "dbhost")
# Get DB name
db_name=$(echo "dbname")
# Get user
db_user=$(echo "dbuser")
# Get password
db_pass=$(echo "dbpass")
```

After -

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get host
db_host=$(echo "dbhost")
echo "dbhost: $dbhost"
# Get DB name
db_name=$(echo "dbname")
echo "dbname: $dbname"
# Get user
db_user=$(echo "dbuser")
echo "dbuser: $dbuser"
# Get password
db_pass=$(echo "dbpass")
echo "dbpass: $dbpass"
```

#### Explanation

```
:g/[(]echo "/s/echo "\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)$/echo "\1"\2^Mecho "\1: $\1"/
```

in pieces -

```
:g/pat/cmd
```

This says "globally" on every line matching "pat" do "cmd".
My "pat" was your `(echo "`, and my "cmd" is a substitution.

```
s/echo "\([^"]*\)"\(.*\)$/echo "\1"\2^Mecho "\1: $\1"/
```

I said to substitute the `echo "..."...` and remember what was between the quotes as 1, and anything after as 2.

The replace part says to put back whatever was there (`echo "\1"\2`) followed by a bit of chicanery.

By hitting ***CTRL-V*** I entered quote-mode, which allowed me to hit ***CTRL-M*** to insert a *carriage return*, which `vim` converts on execution to a newline, at least on the versions I have used.

It's a trick. It can be handy to know and use, but always bear in mind that such things are basically hackery. *Caveat Scriptor.*

I followed that with a formatted `echo "\1: $\1"` to add the lines you wanted.

Comment: Ctrl-V is not hackery, it is a normal (and valuable to know) part of Vim: `:help c_ctrl-v`

Comment: Huh. I was using the trick from the command line. I hadn't realized the trick I was using on the command line was probably from setting `set -o vi`, lol